# Ruby on Rails - Using callback to multiply two objects in separate tables when new entry is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

I have 3 tables, Goals, Activities and Goal_Activities. Goal has a set value for xp and Activity takes an input from the user. Using the on_create method in Activity, I'd like to multiply the user input with the goal xp and store that in the Goal Activities table so I can keep a record of each update and eventually add them all together to create a total goal xp in the Goal table.

I've found a couple of questions on SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416069/ruby-on-rails-create-a-record-from-another-model) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577715/calculation-in-model-or-controller), that cover similar topics but I'm finding it hard to get my head around the associations between the model files and how to access certain methods in different models.

I've also read the documentation on [callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#creating-an-object) which I think is what I need to setup but if there's a better way of doing it, please let me know.

Here are my model associations at the moment.

goal.rb

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :goal_activities
  has_many :activities, through: :goal_activities
end
```

goal_activity.rb

```
class GoalActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :goal
  belongs_to :activity
end
```

activity.rb

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :goal_activities
  belongs_to :goal, through: :goal_activities
end
```

Here are a set of example values in the tables.

Goals

> goal_id: 1, xp: 500, total_goal_xp: default 0

Activities

> activity_id: 1, quantity: 3, goal_id: 1

Goal_activities

> goal_activity_id: 1, goal_id: 1, activity_id: 1, total_xp: 1500

The total_xp would then be added to the total_goal_xp in the Goal table once the activity has been created.

Any advice would be appreciated. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`after_create`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_create) callback in your `activity.rb` as

```
after_create :set_total_xp

private

def set_total_xp
  goal_activity = self.goal_activities.where(goal_id: goal_id).first_or_initialize
  goal_activity.update_attribute(:total_xp, (quantity*goal.xp))
end
```

Comment: I'm assuming this would be in the goal_activities model? Would I still need to initialize the goal_id or activity_id anywhere in the same class? Also does the goal_activities know that the on_create method should be executed when the activity is created and not the goal?

Comment: nope, it should be in activity model...I am assuming here that the associated models are created already..

Comment: `belongs_to` association doesn't need through, remove it

Comment: Thank you. When I create an activity now, I'm getting an error message saying "undefined method `update_attributes' for #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []> Did you mean? update_all". Any idea why that might be?

Comment: my bad...check the update and it is `update_attribute` not `attributes`

Comment: Updated the update_attribute and added .first. Slightly different error this time but along the same lines. `NoMethodError in ActivitiesController#create` `undefined method 'update_attribute' for nil:NilClass`. Probably a stupid question but do I need to create a GoalActivities Controller?

Comment: That means the associated model is not created...check update

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank you very much for your help sir.

Comment: Hi @Md. Farhan Memon, could you take a quick look at my related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44484979/ruby-on-rails-sum-calculation-not-working-with-associations-in-model) please? It should be so simple but I can't get it working....

Comment: Hi @Md. Farhan Memon, I'm recreating my website using methods rather than having column names storing the values but I've run into an issue calling the method. It works in a table but if I try and use the method in a chart, it is returning 'no data'. If you have a minute, could you take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46633453/incorrect-result-when-returning-result-of-a-method-in-another-associated-class) please.