# Ruby on Rails - Sum calculation not working with associations in model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a User table with a column `total_user_xp` with a `has_many :goals` association.

The Goal table has a column `total_goal_xp` which is calculated in the model with the following method:

```
# goal.rb

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :goal_activities
  has_many :activities, through: :goal_activities

def total_goal_xp
    self.total_goal_xp = self.goal_activities.sum(:total_xp)
end
```

For some reason, in my controller and model file for User, I can't calculate the sum for `total_goal_xp` where the user_id matches the current_user. It always returns the value 0 as if the total_goal_xp wasn't being stored in the table.

I'm fairly new to rails but I have a feeling my `total_goal_xp` method isn't saving the value to the db. It seems to recalculate the sum every time that method is called. That said, in the rails console, running Goal.all gives me a table which does have the correct values so I don't understand why the following methods return the value 0.

user_controller.rb

```
def show
    @user_goals = current_user.goals.all
    @user_xp = @user_goals.sum(:total_goal_xp)
end
```

user.rb

```
has_many :goals

def set_total_user_xp
  goal = self.goals.all
  self.total_user_xp = goal.sum(:total_goal_xp)
end
```

In the server log, I get the following SQL - `SELECT SUM("goals"."total_goal_xp") FROM "goals" WHERE "goals"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]` for both methods.

I know I shouldn't be doing the calculations in the controller but at the moment, I just want to get the calculation to work so I know the associations are working.

Would appreciate any advice on the best practice for saving the `total_goal_xp` and the doing the same for the total_user_xp.

Let me know if you'd like to see any other files.

Comment: comment `total_goal_xp` method and see if it returns proper values

Comment: I've removed the `total_goal_xp` method, refreshed the page showing `current_uder.total_user_xp` but it still gives me the value 0. Here's the `total_user_xp` method - `self.goals.sum(:total_goal_xp)`. SQL hasn't changed either. Reloaded the console though and the `total_goal_xp` column is obviously blank now so 0 would be the correct value. Is that what you wanted me to do?

Comment: Tried a different method `self.goals.sum(:xp)` and that sum worked fine. `xp` is an input saved by the user, not a calculation. Looks like I can't access the `total_goal_xp` method in the User model even though I've got the associations there and the user_id in the Goal table. You mentioned initializing last time. Is this something I'd need to do this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have defined method name same as attribute/column name, that's a conflict.
Secondly, if you want to calculate the total on the go, you don't need those columns.

One way I would solve this as the columns are present, set the total value when the values are changed using callback mentioned in this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44435054/6548745)

```
def set_total_xp
  goal_activity = self.goal_activities.where(goal_id: goal_id).first_or_initialize
  goal_activity.update_attribute(:total_xp, (quantity*goal.xp))
  goal = Goal.find_by_id(goal_id)
  user = goal.user
  goal.update_attribute(:total_goal_xp, goal.goal_activities.sum(:total_xp))
  user.update_attribute(:total_user_xp, user.goals.sum(:total_goal_xp))
end
```

OR you don't even need to recalculate sum everytime

```
def set_total_xp
  goal_activity = self.goal_activities.where(goal_id: goal_id).first_or_initialize
  goal_activity.update_attribute(:total_xp, (quantity*goal.xp))
  goal = Goal.find_by_id(goal_id)
  xp = goal_activity.total_xp
  goal.update_attribute(:total_goal_xp, (goal.total_goal_xp + xp))
  goal.user.update_attribute(:total_user_xp, (user.total_user_xp + xp))
end
```

Now you don't need those methods and also, when displaying the data, there's no query hit to the db..

Comment: Thanks, would I need to make any changes to the associations? I'm getting an error message `NoMethodError (undefined method 'includes' for #<Goal:0x007fa9f08e0638>):`. Here are the associations at the moment - `Activity: belongs_to :goal, has_many :goal_activities` `GoalActivity: belongs_to :goal, :activity` `Goal: belongs_to :user, has_many :goal_activities, has_many :activities, through: :goal_activities` `User: has_many :goals`

Comment: try removing `includes` from both the objects `goal` and `user`.

Comment: check the alternate solution

Comment: Thanks again @Md. FarhanMemon, really appreciate the help.