# Incorrect result when returning result of a method in another associated class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 objects, `User` and `Goal` (`User has_many :goals` and `Goal belongs_to :user`)

In my `Goal` model, I have..

```
def total_goal_xp
  total_activities_sum = self.activities.sum(:quantity)
  return (total_activities_sum*xp_value)
end
```

In my `User` `show.html.erb` file, I'm using Google charts to create a pie chart and pulling in the data from my `Goal` model.

```
<%= pie_chart @goals.group(:name).sum(&:total_goal_xp) %>
```

For some reason, I can access the parts that are in the `goal` table for example `:name` but it won't let me return the results from the `Goal` method I included above.

Here's my `users_controller` file...

```
def show
  @goals = current_user.goals
  @activities = current_user.activities.reverse
end
```

Update: I've now changed the line in the show.html.erb file to...

```
<%= pie_chart @goals.group(:name).sum(@goals.each.sum { |p| p.xp_value * p.activities.sum(:quantity) }) %>
```

Now it displays the pie chart but rather than breaking the xp down by the individual total xp for each goal_id, it simply takes the total xp of all the goals and assigns that value to each goal_id. I have 6 goals and each one has 16.7% of the chart and the same value xp when I hover over it.

Second Update: I've moved the pie chart into the Goal view folder in a file called dashboard.html.erb and created a method in the Goal controller called dashboard. I've changed the line of code for the pie chart to...

```
<%= pie_chart @goals.group(:name).sum(@goals.each.sum { |p| p.total_goal_xp }) %>
```

This still gives me the exact same result as the line above. It takes the total value and assigns it to every goal so they're split equally. Does anyone know what is wrong with my sum and why it isn't calculating the result for each goal rather than all of them?

Third update: I've moved the dashboard back to the User view folder and created a method in my User controller called dashboard. I've changed the line of code in the dashboard to...

```
<%= pie_chart @goals.group(:name).sum(@goals.sum.each { |p| p.total_goal_xp }) %>
```

Basically I've switched the order of `sum` and `each` but now it's giving me the following SQL error message...

```
SQLite3::SQLException: wrong number of arguments to function SUM(): SELECT SUM() FROM "goals" WHERE "goals"."user_id" = ?
```

Fourth Update: I've added the map function before the sum. Here's the new line of code...

```
<%= pie_chart @goals.group(:name).map(&:total_goal_xp).sum(&:total_goal_xp) %>
```

This gives me the following error..

```
undefined method `total_goal_xp' for 700:Fixnum
```

700 is the correct `total_goal_xp` value for the first goal so I feel like I'm close but I don't know what else to try. I've tried map().sum, that still gives me `no data`. I've tried without the sum and that returns a blank.

Fifth Update: I've removed .sum() after .map() and added find_by(:goal_id) and it's now giving me an error with the array and every correct value is in it. How can I get it to display this?

Here's the full error message..

```
undefined method `find_by' for [700, 500, 250, 2000, 500, 0]:Array
Did you mean?  find
               index_by
               find_all
               min_by
```

Comment: Have you added the relationships in the models. Can you check the value of current_user in the show method.

Comment: Yes I have User has_many :goals and Goal belongs_to :user. The current_user.id is returning 4 which is the correct id for the user I'm signed in as. I'm also using the Devise gem if that makes any difference.

Comment: Please provide the required output. In case you don't know, trial and error with hardcoded array and see if you are getting expected results, next step would be to produce that array. Basically, activerecord and array methods are messing it up interchangeably.

Comment: The pie chart should show the result of the total_goal_xp method for each goal which is `goal.xp_value * goal.activities.sum(:quantity)` all in one pie chart. I have a table on the right of the pie chart which uses the `@goals.each do` loop to run through all the goals and display the value in the table. If this is what you mean by reproduce the array, then it seems to work fine. What other tests would you recommend?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my method which means it's not able to loop through the goals. Am I missing anything from the line `total_activities_sum = self.activities.sum(:quantity)`?

Comment: Is there a way of creating an instance variable/hash in my controller which has the goal.name and goal.total_goal_xp?

Comment: What is the output of this line `@goals.group(:name)` ? P.S. tag me when you reply, otherwise I won't get notified.. :)

Comment: If I just have `<%= @goals.group(:name) %>`, it displays `#<Goal::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007f64418796d0> 
Value
undefined NaN
undefined NaN
undefined NaN
undefined NaN
undefined NaN
undefined NaN`. Thanks @Md.FarhanMemon :)

Comment: But if I have it working where it splits the pie chart by 6, that does display the correct names along the side of the pie chart. It just doesn't calculate the total_goal_xp properly... @Md.FarhanMemon

Comment: Not the view, tell me what activerecord output it gives from the console.

Comment: My bad, here it is... `Goal Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "goals".* FROM "goals" WHERE "goals"."user_id" = ? GROUP BY "goals"."name"  [["user_id", 4]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT SUM("activities"."quantity") FROM "activities" INNER JOIN "goal_activities" ON "activities"."id" = "goal_activities"."activity_id" WHERE "goal_activities"."goal_id" = ?  [["goal_id", 11]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT SUM("activities"."quantity") FROM "activities" INNER JOIN "goal_activities" ON "activities"."id" = "goal_activities"."activity_id" WHERE "goal_activities"."goal_id" = ?  [["goal_id", 12]]` Is this what you meant @Md.FarhanMemon?

Comment: Nope, that's the sql. Share the result of this query